# Error in python : name '...' is not defined

Tags: python, arrays, linux

I am using a list to store some values.

Sample code:

```
for i in range(3):
  print i
  lst[i] = i+1
  print lst[i]
```

But i am getting an error like this:

```
lst[i] = i+1
NameError: name 'lst' is not defined
```

Is it required to initialize an array in python? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Before the loop do `lst = []` (And name it something better than that. You're trying to access the index of a list that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Well don't you think you should, at the very least, tell Python what type of object you expect `lst` to be before trying to put stuff in it?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
    for i in range(3):
        print i
        lst[i] = i+1
        print lst[i]
```

there are two things wrong with it

```
1- you havn't initialize your list, the computer doesn't know yet that you are working with a list (like you do in programs where u keep track of a counter variable like count = count + i because it must have a seed value to start with)
2- you cannot append elements to a list with the assignment operator, use the append function for that.
```

so here's the correct code:

```
    lst = []
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        lst.append(i+1)
    print(lst[i])
```

output :
        0
        1
        2
        3

Answer (score 2):

You should initalise lst as list `lst=[]`

```
lst=[]
for i in range(3):
  print i
  lst.append(i+1)
  print lst[i]
```

Another way you can do it; the above 5 lines are equivalent to the following single-line list comprehension, except for the printing:

```
lst=[i+1 for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: I am sorry, your code at line 4 may cause "list assigment index out of range", i am afraid it isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should

```
lst=[]
for i in range(3):
  print i
  lst.append(i+1)
  print lst[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = []
for i in range(3):
    print i
    lst.append(i+1)
    print lst[i]
```

Comment: Some explanations may make this answer better.